# Install python from command line and wait till finished

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, cmd

[The docs](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html) have this command: `pythoninstall.exe /quiet InstallAllUsers=1 PrependPath=1`

But that just kicks off a background process, I want to script this and run other commands after the install is finished.  How can run this as a background process?

Edit: wound up using PS: `Start-Process <path to exe> -NoNewWindow -Wait`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use START /WAIT like this:

```
$ START /WAIT pythoninstall.exe /quiet InstallAllUsers=1 PrependPath=1
```

Comment: this wont work for me because im running it in a container

Comment: What is your container image?

Answer (score 4):

This seems to work for me:

```
Start-Process -FilePath ./python-3.7.6-amd64.exe -ArgumentList "/quiet InstallAllUsers=1 PrependPath=1" -NoNewWindow -Wait
```